# Boolean modifier doesn't work

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode

I want to cut holes into my lantern for some glass, which I will then put in there as surface, with some oldish gold design. But the modifier doesn't work. Maybe it is because of the "opened mesh" how it is defined on the blender manual site:

Only Manifold meshes are guaranteed to give proper results, other cases (especially “opened” meshes, Non-manifold but without any self-intersections) will usually work well, but might give odd glitches and artifacts in some cases."

On the wireframe picture, you can see, that i began modeling with edges only (red) and stopped with edges only (green). [image]Then I selected the 4 upper vertices (green) and filled it with CTRL+F - fill. I did the same with the 4 vertices in the red circle. Is this the reason why it doesn't work? How should I fill it else? [image][image]On the two solid render pictures you can see the boolean Objects: first hidden, second unhidden. I hope you can help me with that?

Comment: The boolean modifier can be tricky, especially with increasing vertex count. Your model looks fairly regular, if there isn't a good reason, you should try to properly model those glass slots. Also if you can avoid it, don't use CRTL F, but insert the faces manually. It might seem like more work, but it will save you a lot of headache down the road.

Comment: I deleted the filled faces, and tried it again but it did not work. I've now cut out with the knife tool the surface i want to be as glass. It works now too. I will do it like this now but thanks anyways.